# Vector similar to, but not quite equal to least squares approximation of another vector

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, terminology, least-squares, pseudoinverse

Suppose we have some vector $V$, and we want to locate the vector $kV$ which best approximates some other vector $J$. The answer $T$, in the least-squares sense, is the vector you get by projecting $J$ orthogonally onto the subspace through $V$. We can compute this using the pseudoinverse (given that T, V, and J are all row vectors)

$$
T = JV^+V = V \frac{\langle V, J \rangle}{\langle V, V \rangle}
$$

There is, however, another vector which I've sometimes run into when deriving things, which is very close, but not exactly equal to the above least-squares vector. That vector $W$ is the unique multiple of $V$ such that $W$, if projected orthogonally onto the subspace through $J$, is equal to $J$ itself. This can also be solved in closed form using the pseudoinverse

$$
W = \frac{V}{V J^+} = V \frac{\langle J, J \rangle}{\langle V, J \rangle}
$$

Here is a quick drawing of what I am talking about:

[image: Picture of vectors]

If the angle between V and J is relatively small, then T and W will be close. In particular, if $||J|| = 1$, then we have that $||T-J|| = \sin(\theta)$ and $||W-J|| = \tan(\theta)$, which are approximately equal whenever $\theta$ is small. So, whenever $W$ appears, I typically interpret it as "approximately $T$".

But I am curious if there is some standard way to interpret $W$ as a useful approximation in its own right, with some rigorous interpretation perhaps in statistics. Does $W$ minimize some other kind of error than the least-squared error? Does it have a name? One way to interpret it is that it's the unique point such that $W$ approximates $J$ better than any scalar multiple of $J$. But, it's a bit strange to think of it this way, as $J$ is typically predetermined and the degree of freedom we have is through scaling $V$, where the least-squared solution would be $T$.

Not sure if this is best here or on the stats StackExchange, but thought I'd ask here first.

Comment: I think it looks backwards, if you move the scalar products to lhs it becomes the usual dot product with normalisation, and should be easier to reason about.

Comment: Makes me think of these downsized solar system things. Like you have a scale factor you like and then you want to show how far away that would be if you scaled it down to something more tangible.

Comment: Hi @Emil, not sure I am following - how do you suggest I rewrite it?

Comment: I am just suggesting that V•J/J•J is easier to reason about. Basically you want V to W ratio to be same as U to J ratio, if I am reading your figure correct

Comment: (Just dot both sides like •W to see my point)

Comment: Are you talking about the identity $||W||/||J|| = ||J||/||T||$?

Comment: I am saying your equation becomes V•W/W•W=V•J/J•J